# Recursive Fibonacci Function

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, x86-16, emu8086

I have an assignment where I have create a Fibonacci suite using recursion. The code below works in some cases, but not all.

```
org 100h
 jmp debut 
val dw 0008h 
debut: 
  push word ptr 0000h 
  push word ptr 0001h 
  call fibo
  Add  sp,04
  hlt 
fibo proc near
  Sub  sp,04
  mov  dx,[sp+6] 
  mov  [sp+02],dx
  add  dx,[sp+8]
  mov  [sp],dx
  cmp  dx,val
  jae  Fin 
  Call Fibo
Fin: 
  ret 04
endp fibo
```

but the problem is when I try to put in VAL a number like 0 or 1 or negative number like -0003h, Will not stop.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ^^

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was using `jae fin` , which is a conditional branch for an unsigned compare. I changed this to use `jge fin` , which is a conditional branch for signed compare.

The code below was modified to work with Microsoft Masm. I'm not sure about using sp as index register in real mode, so I used bp. I changed the two pushes so that the first time through fibo, dx ends up with zero.

I don't think this is what the assignment intended. Normally the input is `n`, and fibo is supposed to return the `nth` fibonacci number in ax (for n = {0,1,2,3,4,...} return {0,1,1,2,3, ...}). This would require fibo to call itself twice, based on fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2).

```
        .286
        .model  tiny,c
        .code
        org     0100h

main    proc    far
        jmp     short debut 
val     dw      00008h
debut:
;       note - push immediate requires 80186 or later cpu 
        push    word ptr 0ffffh ;fib(-2) == -1
        push    word ptr 00001h ;fib(-1) ==  1
        call    fibo
        add     sp,4
        hlt
main    endp

fibo    proc    near
        push    bp              ;real mode doesn't allow [sp...]
        mov     bp,sp           ; using [bp...] instead
        sub     sp,4
        mov     dx,[bp+4] 
        mov     [bp-2],dx
        add     dx,[bp+6]
        mov     [bp-4],dx
        cmp     dx,val
        jge     fin             ;changed this line
        call    fibo
fin:    add     sp,4            ;added this line
        pop     bp              ;added this line
        ret     0               ;changed this line
fibo    endp

        end     main
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @rcgldr for you reply, I tried to create a new code and more simple , but I need to change this instructions

```
xchg dx,[bp+4] 
    xchg dx,[bp+6]
```

with another instructions like mov for example,there is the new program

```
    ORG 100H

jmp debut 

val dw 0005h 
F dw ? 

debut: mov al,1 
mov cx,val    
cmp cx,0000h
je stopp
cmp cx,0001h
je stopp 
push cx 
push 0000h 
push 0001h 
call fibo 
saut: add sp,4 
pop F 
stopp:
hlt 


fibo proc 
push bp 
mov bp,sp 
push dx 
mov cx,[bp+8] 
mov dx,[bp+4] 
add dx,[bp+6] 
inc al 
cmp cl,al 
je fin 
xchg dx,[bp+4] 
xchg dx,[bp+6] 
add sp,6 
call fibo 
jmp saut 

fin: mov [bp+8],dl 
pop dx 
pop bp 
ret 
endp fibo
```